# Showing that a specific function is decreasing in one of its arguments

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Consider the function:

$$\lambda(a,b,N) = \frac{N - \frac{a}{1-a^2}(3-a^N)(1-a^N)}{N - \frac{b}{1-b^2}(3-b^N)(1-b^N)},$$
where $N \in \mathbb{N}$, and $a,b \in [0,1]$.

I want to show that, if $a<b$, then $\lambda(a,b,N+1) - \lambda(a,b,N)<0$ for any $N$.

I'm >99.9% sure that this is true (based on evaluating this function on a grid of values for $a$, $b$, and $N$), but I'm finding very hard to prove that analytically.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully solving your question,

but for any choice of $a$ and $b$,

since $\frac{a}{1-a^2}<\frac{b}{1-b^2}$,

we have $\lambda(a,b,N)>1$ for sufficiently large $N$.

But
$\displaystyle\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \lambda(a,b,N)=1$,

so there have to be infinitely many values of $N$ for which $\lambda(a,b,N+1)<\lambda(a,b,N)$.

Comment: Thank you for checking on that. But I found $\lambda(0.95,0.99,3) \approx 23.88$. I believe you calculated the formula with $(3-a)^N$ instead of $(3-a^N)$, which is indeed slightly smaller than 1.
   
Thanks also for pointing out that it should have been "decreasing" in the title!